Cold start for AnalyzeDocumentAsync with prebuilt model
In an .net framework 4.8 console app, I use the code below (from Azure samples), with a S0 pricing tier, location in France.
Each time I run the app, the first call to AnalyzeDocumentAsync takes around 20 seconds, as if there was a cold start or something.
Then if I let the app opened, and call several time the same code, it takes around 3 seconds, even if I change the image to analyse.
And if I wait around 1 minute before calling again the code, or if I close and reopen the app, it takes again around 20 seconds.
Is this a normal behavior ?
I guess not as it would not be usable in a production mode...
Do I miss something ? An azure configuration maybe ?
The code:
var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\test.jpg");
var credential = new AzureKeyCredential(apiKeyAI);

var client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpointAI), credential);

AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-receipt", stream);

Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis.AnalyzeResult receipts = operation.Value;

Thanks for reading !
I also tried to use the beta Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence rather than Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis, but the behavior is exactly the same.

Is this code working for you? What do you want to achieve? Is it related to the runtime of the code? What behavior are you talking about?

Refer to this doc to improve cold starts

@Sampath, thanks for your answer. The code is working, but as I said the first time the app is running, the answer is very slow. this behavior, meaning being slow at each fist run or after a short period of inactivity, is not acceptable in a production mode.
The link you provide is for Azure function cold start. In my scenario I use a console .net 4.8 (tried with .net core 8, exact same behavior) to directly call the Form Recognizer API.

Time OCR Azure one page
Page Duration (sec) nb words
1 5.47 272
2 5.45 473
3 5.48 457
4 5.52 431
5 5.45 470
6 5.42 445
7 5.47 465
8 5.40 426
9 5.82 484
10 5.68 380

Time OCR Azure from document
Page Range Duration (sec) nb words
1-1 5.57 272
1-2 5.63 745
1-3 5.68 1202
1-4 5.72 1633
1-5 5.88 2103
1-6 5.89 2548
1-7 5.99 3013
1-8 5.92 3439
1-9 6.02 3923
1-10 6.18 4303

@Sampath, what is the point of your answer ? Yes, the average duration is around 5 secs , but that is not the problem, the problem is using .net Azure FormRecognizer SDK, at first start or after a short period of inactivity, the duration is around 20-30 seconds. Then the next calls are indeed around 5 secs. Or do I miss something in your post ?
